# Memory address pointing to a variable number of values

Tags: c++, memory

I'm trying to make a program that can read some information from another process. I use Cheat Engine to find the memory address of whatever I'm looking for and ReadProcessMemory in c++ to get the value.

So far so good. Here is my problem: The process I'm trying to get the information from can have multiples windows open at the same time. I will take notepad++ as an example. With notepad++, I can open as many .txt files as I want. Each of these files' content will have their own memory address. So what I think I need is a memory address with every pointer to every files content as value

Example:

```
Address A = Value 1
Address B = Value 2
Address C = Value 3
```

etc... for all files opened

I would need to find a static address with the value: (address A, address B, address C, etc...).

I don't even know how to look for that... Can a memory address hold an array of values...?

EDIT: Really guys, you think the ONLY purpose of cheat engine is cheating? I'm not trying to cheat or hack anything. I didn't know trying to learn about memory address was wrong... For your info, I'm trying to make my own interface for a program I like. AN INTERFACE, that's not cheating.

Comment: I'm not sure how the question is related to your problem, but addresses can point to the first in several elements, yes.

Comment: Learning to play is usually easier than learning to cheat. And it's arguably more fun as well.

Comment: I'm not trying to cheat... Seriously. I'm trying to make my personal interface. Just because I use Cheat Engine doesn't mean I use it to hack.

Comment: Can a memory address hold an array of values...? - an array of values is stored in a set of memory address not just one address

Comment: Thanks for your useless comment @GeraldSv someone already said that. There is literally 3 comments on my question and you manage to repeat something already said.

Comment: If you want to *automate* an existing application I would recommend looking into [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Also, learning about memory management isn't wrong at all. However, failure to learn is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a program where windows are dynamically allocated, variables related to those windows will generally be dynamically allocated as well.  That means the addresses may be different each time the program runs (depending on what else is in the program's heap at the time).  In order to reliably get those locations, you'd need to start at the top-level static pointer (e.g. the address of the list of windows) and then dynamically follow the chain of dynamically-allocated pointers down to the addresses you are looking for.  Whether CheatEngine can do this, or if it can even be done safely at all, I don't know.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when I find the top-level static pointer, it will still be able to hold only 1 value, so how could it possibly hold the memory address of every windows...? This is the part where I'm lost :/

Comment: If you find the address of the window-list object, then you'll be able (in principle) to iterate over the contents of the list.  That would give you pointers to each window in the list.

Comment: In general, Windows applications do not store window lists or even window handles. Those are stored in kernel space, and managed by the Window Manager. But you don't need this information anyway, because there is a supported automation interface: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Memory only holds numbers.  It may be helpful to think of process memory as a huge list of numbers, each taking a value in the range (0-255).  How those numbers are interpreted as is entirely up to the process (i.e., notepad in your example).  This includes whether or not they are some "value" or perhaps a pointer to some value, etc.